# Comparing badges across SE accounts

Tags: feature-request, badges, user-accounts

I am wondering if there is a way for a user to compare badges they earned across various SE accounts?

For instance, I have 10 badges in one SE site and 20 badges in another. I want to see which 10 of the badges I have earned "overlap" across both accounts, and which badges were only earned in one of those accounts.

This could look like a table with badges listed in rows and accounts in columns, with check marks indicating the accounts in which a given badge has been earned.

Not sure if there are badges that are only specific to certain accounts, but if so, there could be an 'n/a' for those across all other of the user's accounts. Hoping this is the right place to ask this.

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing [Data.SE] or an app/script using the API could probably do fairly well.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting (new to this, so wasn't aware of Data Explorer). Looks like it's using SQL, which I used some before and am interested in re-learning. Sorry if these are naive questions. But how do you know things like the valid values of each variable? I see a 'database schema' when composing a query, but wondering how you know what values to use for conditions. Seems like I am missing something about how this works. Thanks for any help. Would love to write my own query to do what I am asking here. But also appreciate any tips/hints ;)

Comment: Most of the SEDE tables that have any specific set of valid values have a little "i" icon in their schema entry to show the full list. In other cases, the column name will usually point out e.g. what other table's primary key this is a secondary key for, and so on. Fair warning, though; this particular bit of SQL is likely to prove fairly challenging to construct; there are some examples of cross-site queries around on Meta or in the SEDE lists, but they usually require significant boilerplate.

Comment: I like the idea of this as a site feature, not just something that is possible to do. For example, it could highlight for me that there's this one site that I've participated a lot in, but never done any review tasks.